# Jquery if statement in with ajax call

Tags: ajax, if-statement

I am making a ajax call and depending on the result I will swop my img, and fire an alert.  Neither of which are happening, but I can't understand why this isn't happening??

```
  var myd = "";
         $.ajax({                 
              url:"urlencode.php",
              data: data,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) { 
                  myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
                  console.log(myd);
                  if (myd == 'c5:3;'){$(this).attr('src','lightbulboff.png')};    
                },
              error: function (request, status, error) 
               {   
                alert(request.responseText);
                }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` value in your callback is changed; it's now the jqXHR object.  The simplest way to fix this is to bind your callback to the current `this` value:

```
function(data) { 
    myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
    console.log(myd);
    if (myd == 'c5:3;'){$(this).attr('src','lightbulboff.png')};    
}.bind(this)
```

This will "pre-set" the this value of your callback.  Just note that this isn't available in IE8, and so you'd need to shim it.  A shim is available [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

---

The other way to fix this is to "save" the current value of `this`.  Something like:

```
var self = this;
$.ajax(......
    success: function(){
        myd = $('<span />').html(data).find("#Result").text();
        console.log(myd);
        if (myd == 'c5:3;'){$(self).attr('src','lightbulboff.png')};
```

Your callback will "close over" the `self` variable, and still have access to it when the callback runs.